# How to properly setup a bind9 DNS server on a Debian 8.7 droplet

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

I have bind9 setup on my old DO droplet (Debian 7.11) and everything was working great.  I decided to setup a new droplet (Debian 8.7) and configure bind9 today.

On the old Debian 7 droplet I had it configured to be authoritative name server with the following names, `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`.

I registered the `example.com` domainname through GoDaddy, and set it point to my external name servers `ns1.example.com` `ns2.example.com` using their web interface.

However, DNS does not appear to be working on the Debian 8.7 droplet when I tried to set it up.

**named.conf.local**

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

// 107.170.40.252 <= public IP v4

zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/master/db.example.com";
};

zone "252.40.170.107.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/master/db.107.170.40";
};
```

**db.example.com**

```
;
; BIND data file for example.com
;
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. chris.example.com. (
                        1       ; Serial
                        3h      ; Refresh after 3 hours
                        1h      ; Retry after 1 hour
                        1w      ; Expire after 1 week
                        1h )    ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

example.com.        IN      MX      10 mail.example.com.
example.com.        IN      A       107.170.40.252
ns1                     IN      A       107.170.40.252
ns2                     IN      A       107.170.40.252
www                     IN      CNAME   example.com.
```

**db.107.170.40**

```
;
;  Addresses and other host information
;
$TTL 86400
@  IN SOA   example.local. hostmaster.example.local. (
                  2013090501     ; Serial
                  43200          ; Refresh
                  3600           ; Retry
                  3600000        ; Expire
                  2592000)        ; Minimum

40.170.107.in-addr.arpa. IN  NS dns.example.local.

252 IN PTR mail.example.local.
252 IN PTR ns1.example.local.
252 IN PTR ns2.example.local.
```

Any help on this matter would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a setting in the GoDaddy web interface.